# How to convert QAction inside a QMenu to QWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtstylesheets

I want to set icon of QAction using qss file. I cannot set stylesheet to QAction so I want to convert it to a QWidget so that I can add icon to individual actions of QMenu using stylesheet. I know how to do that in code by I want to add Icon of QActions using qss.

```
QMenu* menu = new QMenu();
QAction* newFile = new QAction;
newFile->setText("New File");
menu->addAction(newFile);
```

I want to set icon to QAction in qss.

Comment: QAction is not a widget so it can not be accessed using .qss, what you should use is `QMenu::item`, but you can not access each element of the menu individually.

Comment: Use overload [`QMenu::addAction(const QIcon &icon, const QString &text)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#addAction-1).

Comment: I know I cannot access QAction using .qss so I want to convert it to a QWidget so that I can access its properties.  In QToolBar it has 
    widgetForAction(QAction *action) const through which I can access QAction . So I am looking for something similar in QMenu through which I can access QAction property

Comment: As **eyllanesc** said, a QAction is not a graphic class, there is no point in turning it into a QWidget. This is the QMenu that you want.

Comment: Then how do I access the  particular Qmenu action then I can set  QMenu item in qss

Comment: @Rubina It can not, **you can not access each element of the menu individually**

Comment: @Rubina read http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qmenu

Answer (score 0):

```
QMenu *menu;
menu =new QMenu();

QToolButton *button=new QToolButton(menu);
button->setFixedSize(50,50);
QWidgetAction *action=new QWidgetAction(this);
action->setDefaultWidget(button);
menu->addAction(action);
```

Use QToolButton instead of QAction and you can set the icon using setStyleSheet() or setIcon()